# How to unit test static methods with custom object as return type using JUnit 5

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, junit5

```java
public class Demo{
    public static CustomObject processMethod(String str1, String str2){
        //do something
        Demo1.processMethod1(str1,str2);
        Demo2.processMethod2(str1,str2);
        return custom Object;
    }
}

public class Demo1{
    public static void processMethod1(String str1, String str2){}
}

public class Demo2{
    public static void processMethod2(String str1, String str2){}
}
```

I am new to unit testing. While creating a test for class Demo processMethod, how to skip the execution of processMethod1 and processMethod2?

Comment: Why would you want to skip those methods? A lot of extremely brittle tests are written because people take the term unit testing too literal or too extreme.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel those methods are void , so  I don't want to execute them, I just want to check whether the method is called or not

Comment: I think that is a nonsensical argument. Mocking them because they are void sounds like an excuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware that the void method on mocks does nothing by default!

you can use any of the doThrow(),doAnswer(),doNothing(),doReturn() family of methods from Mockito framework to mock void methods.

For example,

```
Mockito.doThrow(new Exception()).when(instance).methodName();
```

or if you want to combine it with follow-up behavior,

```
Mockito.doThrow(new Exception()).doNothing().when(instance).methodName();
```

or do nothing:

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(spy).methodToMock();
```

or you can call real method

```
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(<objectInstance>).<method>();
<objectInstance>.<method>();
```

Or, you could call the real method for all methods of that class, doing this:

```
<Object> <objectInstance> = mock(<Object>.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this,

```
@Test
public void testProcessMethod() throws Exception {
   try (MockedStatic<Demo> demoMocked = Mockito.mockStatic(Demo.class)) {
        demoMocked.when((str1, str2) -> Demo.processMethod1(str1, str2)).thenAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> null);
        demoMocked.verify(Mockito.times(1), () -> Demo.processMethod1(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()));

        demoMocked.when((str1, str2) -> Demo.processMethod2(str1, str2)).thenAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> null);
        demoMocked.verify(Mockito.times(1), () -> Demo.processMethod2(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()));
   }
}
```