# How do I mock methods of a private final client that's being initialized inside a dependency class?

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, powermock, powermockito

I have a class that looks like this :

```
class A {
    private final B b;

    public A(String x, String y){
        b = new B(x,y);
    }


    public void someMethod() {
        b.externalMethod();
    }
}
```

Now I'm instantiating A inside a drools rule and calling `someMethod()` but I want to avoid call to `externalMethod()`. Is there a way to achieve this ?

I've tried using `mockedConstruction` for `B` but with that I'm facing 2 issues :

1. Mockito only allows 1 static mock per thread, so it won't be feasible if I had multiple clients (of type A) inside a single rule.
2. I am not able to assert exceptions using this as `mockedConstruction` uses a lambda function and doing something like `doThrow(someException).when(b).externalMethod()` would give exception on mock creation itself rather than the method call.

Any help is appreciated. I apologise if language is not clear or I've missed any detail (please mention if any).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75873664/how-to-unit-test-static-methods-with-custom-object-as-return-type-using-junit-5/75874320#75874320

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would try doing it without mocks (if possible). For instance, when is `someException` being thrown in the by b.externalMethod()?
Maybe you can cause this to happen through the `x` and `y` params or some test configuration: this will allow you to have a mock-free test. :)

---

If this isn't possible, I would start looking at the design of this class, which makes it hard to test. The easiest thing you can do would be to use dependency injection and add a constructor of A which receives an instance of B as parameter:

```java
class A {
    private final B b;

    public A(String x, String y){
        this(new B(x,y));
    }
        
    public A(B b){
        this.b = b;
    }
    // ...
}
```

This way, in the test, you'll be able to easily inject the mock:

B mockedB = Mockito.mock(B.class);
A testedA = new A(mockedB);

when(mockedB.externalMethod()).thenThrow(someException);

If you don't like the idea of another public constructor, you can consider at least a package-protected one. But overall, I think a second public constructor would be the way to go, you can use `@RequiredArgConstructor` if you are using Lombok.